# Oracle function is Valid or Not

Tags: sql, oracle

How to check whether function is valid or not in oracle DB currently  installed in My System

like this

```
select * from dual

where 

function_name = 'sum'
```

Comment: whether user defined or system defined function u want to check?
check this query
select * from all_objects where object_type='FUNCTION'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT status
FROM all_objects
WHERE object_name = 'MYFUNCTIONNAME'
AND object_type = 'FUNCTION';
```

Replace `MYFUNCTIONNAME` with the name of the function you wish to check. This will return `VALID` or `INVALID`. If the function is not visible to the current user, it will return no rows.